# Spring-data-elasticsearch meta-data annotations for _version, _id etc

Tags: java, elasticsearch, annotations, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using the `@Id` annotation I can add an `id` field to my model object and when I execute a query the resulting model object will contain the value of the elasticsearch `_id` in the `@Id` annotated field.

However, I have yet to figure out how to get other document meta-data such as the `_version`. I tried adding a `version` field to my model and annotating it with the `@Version` annotation but nothing happened and the field remained `null`.

```
{
    "_index" : "twitter",
    "_type" : "tweet",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_version" : 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source" : {
        "user" : "kimchy",
        "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
        "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
    }
}
```

I'm referring to the fields such as `_index`, `_type`, `_id`, `_version` etc...

I'm especially concerned with `_version` because that is used for optimistic locking.

It seems to me that if `_id` is supported then `_version` and the other meta-data fields should be supported somehow too.

I've just read the spring-data-elasticsearch docs and I can't find anything. If someone knows, please advise.

Are all of the elasticsearch document meta-data fields supported in spring-data-elasticsearch? If so, how?

Further, if I can get the `_version` somehow then how can I use it for optimistic locking when using spring-data-elasticsearch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Near as I can tell, what you're asking for doesn't exist.  Have no real ability to prove that however. I did find a list of annotations for `Spring-data-elasticsearch`:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/package-tree.html

Neither @id nor @version are on that list.

I can find other things that have a `@version` annotation but they aren't `Spring-data-elasticsearch`.

If you were only talking about `Spring-Data` I'd point you at this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Version.html

> org.springframework.data.annotation
>
> Annotation Type Version
>
> @Documented  @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
>
> @Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,ANNOTATION_TYPE}) public @interface
>
> Version Demarcates a property to be used as version field to implement optimistic locking on entities.
>
> Since: 1.5
>
> Author: Patryk Wasik, Oliver Gierke

Here's a link to some code using it:

http://hantsy.blogspot.com/2013/10/spring-data-new-perspective-of-data.html

Not sure if this is what you want but that's as close as I can come.  It is for optimistic locking.